# crontab does not run

Tags: cron, screenshot, scripts

i have added a script to run every min

like this

```
crontab -e
```

and then add this code

```
* * * * * /bin/sh /home/user/Public/call.sh
```

the code did not run

then i restarted the cron

```
sudo /etc/init.d/cron restart
```

and try this too

```
sudo service cron restart
```

but still the code did not work

i can use graphical schedule task app but i dont want to use it but use command line

the code is just to take screen shot every min

```
#!/bin/sh

now=$(date +"%m_%d_%Y-%T")
import -window root .folder/Image$now.png
```

and file permission is 777 too

if i run this script directly it works perfectly but in crontab

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that `.folder` exists in your home directory.

And the most important part is to modify your script like this

```
#!/bin/sh

now=$(date +"%m_%d_%Y-%T")
export DISPLAY=:0
import -window root .folder/Image$now.png
```

Basically you are including this line in your script. `export DISPLAY=:0`

Restart your cron. You should see that working.

**NOTE:** Its a nice idea, I am using it on my machine now :) Thanks.